# group inside a list of objects and modify

Tags: c#, list, object, arraylist

I got a list from a class like this:

```
List<clsLinkObject> FinalValsLinks = new List<clslinkObject>();
```

and the class contains:

```
public class clsLinkObject
    {
        public string clientCode { get; set; }
        public string clienteName { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }

    }
```

It is filled through the program with FinalValsEnlaces.Add(myLinkObj);
So it ends up with a list of objects whose clientCode can be repeated. I need to group up the repeated ones and add its units:

- select all the clientCode that are repeated.
- Add all those units
- Delete them and just add one with the total.

So, is there any easy and straightforward way to do it, or just iterate through them and create a new object?
In case the iteration way was the easier, would it be better to create a new object or modify the one i have?

```
foreach(var objadd in FinalValsLinks)
{//count and add
string tmpclientN= "";
tmpclientN = objadd.clientCode 

...
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using Linq.

The below linq statement, group based on the `clientCode` and return the grouped (unique) records with sum of units.

```
finalValsLinks = finalValsLinks.GroupBy(f => f.clientCode).Select(g => 
        {
            var first = g.First();
            return new clsLinkObject() {clientCode = first.clientCode, clienteName = first.clienteName, units = g.Sum(c => c.units)};
        }).ToList();
```

I've changed the definition of units to `int`. In case, you have requirement to have units as string, then you can add the `int.Parse` or `double.Parse` during the `Sum` operation.

See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVvUUB) dotnet fiddle created to demo the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your case can be answered using `GroupBy` and `Select` LINQ functions. But, I think in your particular case that would not be a correct approach since you accumulate the same data and it's wrong to pay the price of LINQ queries.

Keep in mind that the LINQ expressions, although simple in syntax, don't play some miracle runtime and actually pay the price of the operations.

So, my solution for you is to use `Dictionary` (maybe in conjunction with a list) like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); //The second string is the type of unit. Which might be wrong.

void AddValue(ClsLinkObject clsLinkObject)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(clsLinkObject.clientCode))
    {
        dictionary[clsLinkObject.clientCode] += clsLinkObject.units;
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary.Add(clsLinkObject.clientCode, clsLinkObject.units);
    }
    //You might add to your list as well, if you really want the list here.
}
```

You can also make a `Collection` class to handle both dictionary and list in one location which I like it a lot.

If by any chance you absolutely want the group by solution tell me and I will update.

**P.S** 
Your unit might not be `string` maybe.
And in C# it is a convention to name your classes with PascalCasing